# Show facets on non-search pages - not working?

Tags: 7, search

I have Apache Solr search (not Solr for search api) set up and working but I can't get it to show facets on non-search pages.

I've tried every imaginable configuration of "Show facets on non-search pages not working" and "path" on the facet settings page but nothing seems to work.

Does this feature actually work? And if so how?

Comment: Facets don't normally show where there isn't an associated view on the page. How would they work given they are meant to filter what's listed? Can you explain what you want them to do?